# Do simple home wifi routers have DNS capabilities?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns

I have a Medialink MWN-WAPR300N and I would like to add the name of my laptop to it so it can be accessed on the home network via the name and not just the IP.  I need to do that because I am working with an application that relies on an SSL certificate that is based on the domain name.

All I got out of Googling when I searched for "home wifi DNS" as well as the Admin Console of the router itself was how to change which DNS server the home network is connected to but I couldn't see any DNS capabilities to add names and resolve them to IP addresses.  I was wondering if this functionality even is possible with a simple home wifi router.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not. You'd have to run your own DNS server and point your router's DNS entries to it. The router simply queries whatever is requested from its configured servers. Alternatively, you can edit your `hosts` file.